# How can I mock pouchDB documents?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, automated-tests, pouchdb

I have the following function and I want to write specs for it in **jasmine***.

```
function getData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        myDB.query('testview/testfn', {key: false, include_docs: true}).then(function(result){
            var testdata = result.rows;
            if(testdata.length){
                resolve(testdata[Math.floor(Math.random() * testdata.length)].doc);
            }else{
                resolve();
            }
        }, function(error){
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Here in the above code, **myDB** is an instance of **pouchDB**. Basically I am new to Jasmine and I need to write test for above function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check Mocking in Jasmine. For example, you can read about `jasmine.createSpyObj` ([docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3EcreateSpyObj%3C/code%3E))

You can mock localDB and its method: `query`. Then you can verify that method interacts with the mock correctly.

```
it("Verify getting random song", function() {
  localDB = jasmine.createSpyObj('localDB', ['query']);
  getRandomSong();
  expect(localDB.query).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'song/downloadStatus',
      jasmine.objectContaining({key: false, include_docs: true}));
  // more expects.
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @laroslav

Comment: How can I test the flow after getting result of localDB.query().Should I mock its result and write test accordingly , if yes then how can I mock it as its a promise?

Comment: I would consider at least two approaches. 1. If callback is multi-line function - try to extract it to a separate method, then test them separately. 2. You can resolve promise and check results. Here is a post to rump-up: https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/testing-javascript-promises